# django html template not loading from generic view from model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

### Introduction

I am currently working on a small piece of the project to understand more about the Django ORM and to display individual objects. Using Generic views to keep the code clean. (I am somewhat new to Django Framework)

### Goal

The goal of this piece is to show how many users have written an article. For example, I have total of 4 articles. I need to show how many articles written by each user.

My console output:

| User | Article Count |
| --- | --- |
| testuser | 2 |
| testuser1 | 2 |
| testuser2 | 0 |

my output on the HTML template:

| User | Article Count |
| --- | --- |
| testuser | 0 |
| testuser1 | 0 |
| testuser2 | 0 |

### Problem

I am not understanding why my console output is correct, but my HTML template isn't showing the results. Please HELP me understand why it is doing this!!!!! If there is a similar post let me know! I have been looking everywhere for the answer, but I couldn't find it on the internet.

### Code

**views.py**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Article
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_list.html'
    context_object_name='article_list'
    queryset=Article.objects.order_by('-date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)        
        users = get_user_model().objects.all()
        context["users"] = users
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            article_count = articles.filter(author__exact=user).values('author').count()
            # works with and without str() function
            context['article_count'] = str(article_count)
            # My console output is correct
            print(str(user) + ': ' + str(articles.filter(author__exact=user).values('author').count()))

        return context
```

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**article_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Articles{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

   <!-- This is for checking if the articles exist. Nothing to worry here. Output is 4 -->
  {% if article_count > 0 %}
    <p>{{article_count}} There are articles in this list</p>
  {% else %}
   <p>There are no articles in this list</p>
  {% endif %}

  <!-- Main source of the problem!! -->
  {% for user in users %}
    <p>{{user}} = {{article_count}}</p>
  {% endfor %}

  <!-- Displays data from database. Nothing to worry here. -->
  {% for article in article_list %}
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">{{ article.title }}</span> &middot;
        <span class="text-muted">by {{ article.author }} | {{ article.date }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        {{ article.body }}
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer text-center text-muted">
        <a href="{% url 'article_edit' article.pk %}">Edit</a> |
        <a href="{% url 'article_delete' article.pk %}">Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Hopefully is organized enough to understand the problem. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where do you pass `article_count` to the template? Since you do not pass this to the template `article_count` does not exists, hence it will go to the `{% else %}` case.

Comment: I am not sure where I would pass ```article_count```, can you explain it in better detail? If I add ``` context['article_count']=articles.filter(author__in=users).values('author').count() ``` then I would get all 4 articles to each user. And that isn't the goal. if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just rewriting the `article_count` variable in your for loop, so, the context gets assigned only to the last calculated value. You might create a dictionary something like `{"user": {"object": user, "article_count": article_count}}` for each user, and assign this dictionary to the context after making calculation for all of them, however, it is still not a clear way.

Best way would be to assign a related name for the connection:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="articles",
    )
```

And then, assign users to your context in the view:

```py
context["users"] = get_user_model().objects.all()
```

In your template, you can now show the result like this:

```html
{% for user in users %}
    <p>{{ user }} = {{ user.articles.count }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Emin!! I didn't realize I was missing that small piece. I still have much to learn about this amazing framework!! I also didn't know ``` user.articles.count ``` can be used in the html template view. That is really good to know!!